# Knife ec2 command fails with this error

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to spin up a server on AWS using the knife ec2 command. But the knife command fails with this error;

```
ERROR: You have not provided a valid image (AMI) value.
```

I start by listing the servers I already have on Amazon.

```
[root@localhost .chef]# knife ec2 server list --region us-west-2

Instance ID  Name         Public IP     Private IP    Flavor    Image         SSH Key  Security Groups  IAM Profile  State  
i-ced19d0b   webserver-1  52.27.79.224  172.31.37.89  t2.micro  ami-d5c5d1e5  visa     launch-wizard-2               running
```

As you can see above I have a  single server (webserver-1) with IP address 52.27.79.224.

I created this server manually on the AWS console.

Okay when I run the knife ec2 command it gives the following error:

```
[root@localhost .chef]# knife ec2 server create -S visa  -I ami-d5c5d1e5 --region=us-west-2

ERROR: You did not provide a valid 'Image' value.
```

I tried the same command without the –region option. It still gave the same error as seen below.

```
[root@localhost .chef]# knife ec2 server create -S visa -I ami-d5c5d1e5

ERROR: You did not provide a valid 'Image' value.
```

But the image I’m using is the same image I got from running knife server list command as seen below.

```
[root@localhost .chef]# knife ec2 server list --region us-west-2

Instance ID  Name         Public IP     Private IP    Flavor    Image         SSH Key  Security Groups  IAM Profile  State  
i-ced19d0b   webserver-1  52.27.79.224  172.31.37.89  t2.micro  ami-d5c5d1e5  visa     launch-wizard-2               running
```

As you see above I am using the same amazon machine image  ami-d5c5d1e5.

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. I just started learning chef and AWS.

I'm a complete newbie to this. Please help.

By the way I'm using the free trial version of hosted chef.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check that the ami you are trying to create is in region=us-west-2? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638676/resolve-valid-image-value-error

Comment: yes I checked. And it is.

Comment: Thank you duhaime. I followed the link and took a look at the list of servers for US West. And NOW EVERYTHING WORKS FINE.

Comment: I was able to get an ami image id from the list for US  west and now I'm spinning a server in AWS. It is working now. Thank you for responding.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! :) I'd leave the question around in case others hit the same roadblock.

Comment: But now it is hanging on sshd access. This is what I get now:

Comment: [root@localhost .chef]#  knife ec2 server create -S visa -I ami-2b2e181b  --region us-west-2
Instance ID: i-b55d1470
Flavor: m1.small
Image: ami-2b2e181b
Region: us-west-2
Availability Zone: us-west-2b
Security Groups: default
Tags: Name: i-b55d1470
SSH Key: visa

Waiting for EC2 to create the instance.......
Public DNS Name: ec2-52-26-165-53.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Public IP Address: 52.26.165.53
Private DNS Name: ip-172-31-38-160.us-west-2.compute.internal
Private IP Address: 172.31.38.160

Waiting for sshd access to become available..................................

Comment: There are some potential fixes listed here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/3

Comment: Thanks I'm investigating the different options in that link. Really grateful for all your help.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for your help. I finally resolved all the problems. I created the server and successfully logged in via ssh. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: My pleasure! I'm happy to hear all is well.